# Annoying functionality of suggestions in newer version of Google keyboard

Tags: keyboard

I recently updated my version of Android on my Nexus 4 and this is a really annoying thing I noticed.

In previous versions (I was on 4.0), the word that was typed displayed as the middle suggestion.  This was ideal, as I never had to advert my eyes from the soft keyboard (I use the swipe typing, so this makes a **big** difference.

The newer version does not do this; instead, it displays three possible alternates.  It's far less efficient and extremely annoying.

There's no specific setting I can find to change this.  Is there any way to change this back or some obscure commination of settings that will cause this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded an older version of the Google Keyboard app, which gives the preferred functionality.  For reference, it's 4.1.22063.1974169